# Count the total number of keys in first array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => 137585189
            [1] => 138053588
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [0] => 137626141
            [1] => 137672213
            [2] => 137718802
        )
)

Array
(
    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => 137585189
            [1] => 138053588
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [0] => 137626141
            [1] => 137672213
            [2] => 137718802
            [3] => 137732801
        )
)
```

This is the result from:

```
foreach($value as $val){
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($value);
  echo '</pre>';
        }
```

How can sum the total number of keys per Array?

Array = 5

Array = 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do recursive [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php), by giving option `COUNT_RECURSIVE`. You can get what you want by subtracting the recursive count with simple count

```
<?php
$food = array('fruits' => array('orange', 'banana', 'apple'),
              'veggie' => array('carrot', 'collard', 'pea'));

// recursive count
echo count($food, COUNT_RECURSIVE); // output 8

// normal count
echo count($food); // output 2

// to count second level entries
echo (count($food,COUNT_RECURSIVE)-count($food,0)); //output 6

?>
```

Comment: Additional question, how can I get the total number of keys like, 5+6?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COUNT_RECURSIVE` like so

`count($arr, COUNT_RECURSIVE);`

Note that this includes the inner array itself so it'll end up being 7 for the first array. 
To fix this, you can just subtract `count($arr)`

Comment: He needs second level count.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php


$array = array(array(array(137585189,138053588),array(137626141,137672213,137718802)), array(array(137585189,138053588), array(137626141,137672213,137718802,137732801)));



foreach($array as $val){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($val);
    echo (count($val,COUNT_RECURSIVE)-count($val,0));

        }

?>
```

[Demo Here>>](http://codepad.viper-7.com/TAldCo)